# XNA and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, xna

I am trying to make a main menu in Windows Forms. When you click a label in the form, the XNA game should start playing.
But it didn't work. 
my code in the program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace _2DSpaceShooter  
{
    if WINDOWS || XBOX
    static class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Application.Run(new MainMenu());
        }
    }
    endif
}
```

My code in the label click event

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Game1 game = new Game1())
    {
        game.Run();
    }
}
```

Please help me!!!
I am sorry for possible English mistakes (I am not American)

Comment: What does happen when you click the label? Even the game were to  appear at this point, I expect calling Game.Run inside the click event handler is going to enter the game loop and never return, leaving your WinForms UI unable to respond to any other user input. You should probably spawn a new thread in the event handler and have that create the game and call Run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it, but if you can one of the simplest way is by using [GameComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx). Making your game as a GC enables you to launch multiples parts of it at one time, without having issues with threads.

Answer (score 0):

As @eudabash mentioned in the comment section, you'll need to do the game.Run() in a seperate thread:

```
Game1 game = new Game1();

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    game.Run();
};
thread.Start();
```

or, if you're on .Net 4.0 (I think. Or even 3.5)

```
Game1 game = new Game1();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    game.Run();
}
```

Optionally make 'game' a field in your Form1 class, so you can access it anywhere. Just make sure to only retrieve data from Game, and never edit the UI from within Game. Cross-thread operations and whatnot. If you need to, remember to invoke.